# Antivirus prevents setup program from running

Tags: c#, setup-deployment

Hi all: 
I'm working on a visual Studio setup program. The problem is that the antivirus (AVG) reports that I don't have enough permissions to run the setup program. When I disable the antivirus, the setup works fine. My setup does't modify the registry and it is so simple. It just installs a program in the program files(x86). I log in to my computer as administrator and I run the setup as administrator too. 
Could anyone point out how I can bypass the antivirus?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can add an exception in the Anti-virus.

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080816043929AAB4mQw

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the Visual Studio is launching a virtual Internet server (http://localhost:SomePortNumber) for your project to be executed. That creates a listening socket that AVG thinks is a threat to your system.

Comment: @Ahmed: Why would it do so? My program does't have any reference to internet connection. By the way, I'm running the setup from a flash memory and I've noticed the AVG has created a sandbox on the flash drive.

Comment: Maybe your project uses references to DLL that causes your machine to Listen to connections?

Comment: @Ahmed: That is possible. I think that happens when the setup tries to download the prerequisites like windows installer or .net framework. If this is the case, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem with antivirus programs blocking installations. We later found that many anti-virus programs block (by default) system modifications by an application that is not signed by a digital certificate. We overcame this issue in the wild by signing our assemblies (including the setup) with a digital certificate from a reputable CA.